# Load Data Local Infile SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, load

I have an extract of data that is separated by using this character  |

I need to load this data into a MySQL database table but I'm struggling with the lines terminated by function.

Can anyone please help me identify the correct method to terminate these fields? My example data is below.

I've already tried '"|"' but this doesn't work for the first and last fields.

**Example:**

```
00000000|OLD TRUCK|9|13|02|Z |Z  |9999|111|99|ZZ|ZZ|ZZ|ZZ||ZZ|ZZ|99|999|2
```

Comment: what u want to terminate?

Comment: Please show us a example of what you have tried that failed.

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'example.txt' INTO TABLE example table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'example.txt' INTO TABLE example table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '"|"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'example.txt' INTO TABLE example_table
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
 LINES TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Comment: I've just tried this and it doesn't quite work. It inserts a record with double quotes either side e.g. "data". Its like this on every field

Comment: What if he has more  than a rows or a new line , while loading ??

Comment: Yeah I have thousands of lines but each line just ends with the value... See my original example, that is one single row andI have many more like that

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'd:/test.csv' INTO TABLE test
>
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
>
> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';